# Kibana: Search within text for string

Tags: search, elasticsearch, kibana

I have A log message in Kibana that contains this:

```
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:597)
```

Actual search that isn't returning results: log_message: "hibernate3"

If I search for "hibernate3" this message will not appear.  I am using an Elasticsearch template and have indexed the field, but also want to be able to do case-insensitive full-text searching.   Is this possible?

Template that is in use:

```
{
"template": "filebeat-*",
"mappings": {
    "mainProgram": {
        "properties": {
            "@timestamp": {
                "type": "date",
                "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
            },
            "@version": {
                "type": "text"
            },
            "beat": {
                "properties": {
                    "hostname": {
                        "type": "text"
                    },
                    "name": {
                        "type": "text"
                    }
                }
            },
            "class_method": {
                "type": "text",
                "fielddata": "true",
                "index": "true"
            },
            "class_name": {
                "type": "text",
                "fielddata": "true"
            },
            "clientip": {
                "type": "ip",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
            },
            "count": {
                "type": "long"
            },
            "host": {
                "type": "text",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
            },
            "input_type": {
                "type": "text",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
            },
            "log_level": {
                "type": "text",
                "fielddata": "true",
                "index": "true"
            },
            "log_message": {
                "type": "text",
                "index": "true"
            },
            "log_timestamp": {
                "type": "text"
            },
            "log_ts": {
                "type": "long",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
            },
            "message": {
                "type": "text"
            },
            "offset": {
                "type": "long",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
            },
            "query_params": {
                "type": "text",
                "index": "true"
            },
            "sessionid": {
                "type": "text",
                "index": "true"
            },
            "source": {
                "type": "text",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
            },
            "tags": {
                "type": "text"
            },
            "thread": {
                "type": "text",
                "index": "true"
            },
            "type": {
                "type": "text"
            },
            "user_account_combo": {
                "type": "text",
                "index": "true"
            },
            "version": {
                "type": "text"
            }
        }
    },
    "access": {
        "properties": {
            "@timestamp": {
                "type": "date",
                "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
            },
            "@version": {
                "type": "text"
            },
            "beat": {
                "properties": {
                    "hostname": {
                        "type": "text"
                    },
                    "name": {
                        "type": "text"
                    }
                }
            },
            "clientip": {
                "type": "ip",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
            },
            "count": {
                "type": "long",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
            },
            "host": {
                "type": "text",
                "index": "true"
            },
            "input_type": {
                "type": "text",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
            },
            "log_timestamp": {
                "type": "text"
            },
            "log_ts": {
                "type": "long",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
            },
            "message": {
                "type": "text"
            },
            "offset": {
                "type": "long",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
            },
            "query_params": {
                "type": "text",
                "index": "true"
            },
            "response_time": {
                "type": "long"
            },
            "sessionid": {
                "type": "text",
                "index": "true"
            },
            "source": {
                "type": "text",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
            },
            "statuscode": {
                "type": "long"
            },
            "tags": {
                "type": "text"
            },
            "thread": {
                "type": "text",
                "index": "true"
            },
            "type": {
                "type": "text",
                "index": "true"
            },
            "uripath": {
                "type": "text",
                "index": "true"
            },
            "user_account_combo": {
                "type": "text",
                "index": "true"
            },
            "verb": {
                "type": "text",
                "index": "true"
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to your scenario, what you're looking for is an **analyzed** type `string` which would first analyze the string and then index it. A quote from the [doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/mapping-intro.html#_index_2).

> In other words, index this field as full text.

Thus make sure that, you have your mapping of the necessary fields properly so that you'll be able to do a *full-text* search on the docs.

Assuming that, in `Kibana` if the log line is under the field `message`, you could simply search for the word by:

```
message:"hibernate3"
```

You might also want to refer [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/term-vs-full-text.html), to identify the variance between `Term Based` and `Full-Text`.

**EDIT**

Have the mapping of the field `log_message` as such:

```
"log_message": {
       "type": "string", <- to make it analyzed
       "index": "true"
}
```

Also try doing a **wildcard** search as such:

```
{"wildcard":{"log_message":"*.hibernate3.*"}}
```

Comment: For some reason this isn't working:  

    log_message:".hibernate3." returns no results. --

Where log_message is a subset of message.   My ElasticSearch template has this as indexed:  log_message type text index TRUE

Comment: Updated template above

Comment: So you mean, you don't see a separate field called `log_message` in Kibana?

Comment: And also could you try searching it as a `wildcard`, like `log_message:"*.hibernate3.*"` between asterisks? I've updated the answer!

Comment: I should note that you are out-of-luck if your search query contains spaces.  Neither `log_message:"*the quick brown*"` nor `log_message:*the quick brown*` work as intended.  Why is KQL so non-intuitive like this?

Comment: @JonathanNeufeld Simply enclose the search with double-quotes, e.g. ```message:"the quick brown fox"```. You don't need asterisks.

Comment: An ugly hack that seems to work is to replace all spaces with asterisks. While not the same as a properly formatted search, it can help filter down to fewer log messages. `log_message: *the*quick*brown*` ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 29):

```
message: *.hibernate3.*
```

also works (please note, that no quotes are needed for that)

Comment: What if your query has spaces? i.e. `message:*the quick brown fox*` does not work, neither does enclosing it in double-quotes.  Basic search features like this are half a century old, strange how reinventing this wheel today results in an inferior wheel.

Comment: What @JonathanNeufeld said.  It blows my mind that Kibana lacks some of these drop-dead basic textual query features.

Comment: you don't need the asterisks

Comment: If your query has spaces you can use `%` (percent sign) like this: `message: "%Cannot open connection%"`. Based on @Olivier Tonglet answer.

Answer (score 12):

With Kibana 6.4.1 I used the "%" as wildcard.

```
message: %hibernate3%
```

Answer (score 4):

**For me it was because I was using the *".keyword"*.**

My key was called "message" and I had "message" and "message.keyword" available.

*Full text search isn't working on ".keyword".*

Not working :

```
message.keyword : hello
```

Working :

```
message : hello
```

Comment: In Kibana or OpenSearch dashboard, one has to `add filter` -> `message` `is` `whole word or multiple quoted words`. It will not catch partial words it seems.