# Query Kibana logs where message contains a substring

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am trying to query kibana logs where the message contains the substring "Bla" with the search query - "Bla" and the search query "@message: "*Bla*" ".

The search will find logs with messages that have the word "Bla" with spaces - like a message "The operation failed for object Bla during insert.".

The search will not find logs with a message containing the word "Bla" with no spaces - like a message "Error:Bla,failed for insert.".

How do I make a query the will find both types of messages?

Comment: Seems like the problem was in the Kibana environment setup, in one environment searching "Bla" finds logs with or without spaces before the word. In the other environment, searching "Bla" finds only logs without spaces before the word "Bla". 

I compared all of the settings and indexes between both environments and they look the same.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/71618486/520567

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try searching *Bla* (**Note:** Without any quotes)

Comment: This solves the problem in our Kibana environment that has this problem. Thanks!

Comment: message : *LanaiBotapr1 * Thank you , I wanted to search for this string in whole message , so it helped too.

Comment: no need of the asterisks

Answer (score 3):

You can try with:

- `*Bla*` (Without any quotes) --> search for a string that have "Bla" in any position.

> i.e: diploBlastic, resemBlance etc will be in search result

- `*Bla` (Without any quotes) --> search for a string that will end with "Bla".

> i.e: kiBla, doBla etc will be in search result

- `Bla*` (Without any quotes) --> search for a string that will start with  "Bla".

> i.e: Blank, Black etc will be in search result

Comment: I want to find ? but its a special wildcard character, seems to be no way to esacape it